Active dates in a table
I'm having a table with a date column, like:
*** Events

  | Date                       | Thing  |
  |----------------------------+--------+
  | <2024-11-12 14:00-17:00>   | Foo    |
  | <2024-11-13 09:00-12:00>   | Bar    | 
  | <2024-11-13 14:00-17:00>   | Baz    |

I'm happy those date do appear in the org-agenda view, I really like org-agenda.
Sadly in org-agenda all those dates are labelled with the nearest headline, "Events", so it looks like:
Tuesday    12 November 2024
  julien:     14:00-17:00 Events
Wednesday  13 November 2024
  julien:      9:00-12:00 Events
  julien:     14:00-17:00 Events

which is kind of sad, "Events" is not a helpfull bit of information here. I bet there's a better way!
Obviously I could do a headline per event, but I like it as a table view, it's dense and concise, and I have other columns with formulas on them, so a table is a great fit to store those dates, that's just the label, org-agenda side, that don't fit well.

The agenda is designed with headlines in mind: an agenda entry is produced from the fixed parts of a headline entry (although as you found out, dates are looked for in the text of the entry, but that's the only exception that I know of). You can write a function that somehow produces the "Thing" part of the table row with the given date and customize org-agenda-prefix-format to print it as part of the agend entry. But there is not much support for that: the function is going to be ugly, fairly complicated and very specific to your situation. I'd be surprised if a simple solution exists.

Actually, modifying org-agenda-prefix-format requires the function to be evaluated at agenda construction time which complicates things substantially. I think it would be easier if the function is run by org-agenda-finalize-hook - see this question for some ideas - but even so, what you are asking for is somewhat "unnatural" (in the sense described in my first comment above), so it is still going to be a complicated (and very specific to your situation) function.

Here's an implementation along the lines of my last comment:
#+begin_src elisp

  (defun my/org-agenda-process-dates-in-tables ()
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (not (eobp))
      (let* ((props (text-properties-at (point)))
             (datestr (plist-get props 'dotime)))
        (when (and datestr (string= (plist-get props 'org-category) "julien"))
          (let ((marker (plist-get props 'org-marker))
                (bound (point))
                text)
            (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer marker)
              (goto-char (marker-position marker))
              ;; we should now be at the date in the originating file
              ;; check that the date occurs in a table
              (when (org-at-table-p)
                ;; convert the table to lisp structure and get the required row
                (let* ((table (delq 'hline (org-table-to-lisp)))
                       (row-index (org-table-current-line))
                       (row (nth (1- row-index) table)))
               
                  ;; check that the date matches the field in the first column
                  ;; - note that nth counts from 0.
                  (when (string= (nth 0 row) datestr)
                    ;; select the field in the second column 
                    (setq text (nth 1 row))))))
                  
            ;; edit the agenda entry to add it at the end of the line
            (when text
              (end-of-line)
              ;; attempt to deal with tags - this is *NOT* robust
              (when (and (eq (char-before) ?:) 
                         (search-backward " :" bound t))
                (while (looking-at " ")
                  (backward-char))
                (forward-char)
                ;; +3 for the space and the two parens - see below
                (delete-char (+ 3 (length text))))
              
              (insert (concat " (" text ")"))))))
      (forward-line 1))))

  (add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook #'my/org-agenda-process-dates-in-tables)
#+end_src

The function is run by the hook after the agenda is initialized but just before it is made read-only. For efficiency, it assumes that all such tables are in a single file, julien.org, so that the category of the items coming from that file is julien (see Categories in the manual). If the entry has this category and has a time string, it checks the time string to make sure that it occurs in a table (in column 1) and gets the text of the corresponding column 2. It then edits the agenda buffer to add that text (with a space to separate it from the headline and parens to delimit it). Adding the text and making sure that the alignment is still correct is finicky and the code that does that is not robust: it attempts to deal with tags, and it does a good job in simple cases, but colons in the headline text will confuse it.
Given a julien.org file with this structure:
* Events with time                                                     :with:

  | Date                       | Thing  |
  |----------------------------+--------+
  | <2024-11-12 14:00-17:00>   | Foo    |
  | <2024-11-13 09:00-12:00>   | Bar    | 
  | <2024-11-13 14:00-17:00>   | Baz    |


  
* Event with no time                                                :without:

  | Date         | Thing |
  |--------------+-------|
  | <2024-11-16> | Foo2  |
  | <2024-11-17> | Bar2  |
  | <2024-11-18> | Baz2  |

the agenda will look like this:
Week-agenda (W46):
Monday     11 November 2024 W46
Tuesday    12 November 2024
  julien:     14:00-17:00 Events with time (Foo)                          :with:
Wednesday  13 November 2024
  julien:      9:00-12:00 Events with time (Bar)                          :with:
  julien:     14:00-17:00 Events with time (Baz)                          :with:
Thursday   14 November 2024
Friday     15 November 2024
Saturday   16 November 2024
  julien:     Event with no time (Foo2)                                :without:
Sunday     17 November 2024
  julien:     Event with no time (Bar2)                                :without:


This is huge, I'll have to try it, thanks! I'm not an elisp writer, I can almost understand it though, question is: how does it go working on this kind of code? I mean, I think you're starting small, testing, enhancing, testing, fixing, testing, ...  Do you simply evaluate it from your org file and hit C-a-a to test the result? Maybe adding a small thing to remove it from the hooks before adding it again?

When you point is within a source block, hitting C-cC-c will evaluate it.

"I think you're starting small, testing, enhancing, testing, fixing, testing, ..." - that's right. Once I had decided that the easiest thing would be to use the hook, I wrote a skeleton (following the one that I had written for the question linked in my comment above) and fleshed it out a bit at a time. I did the testing by adding the code to the julien.org file itself in a Code section as an Elisp code block and evaluated the code block with C-c C-c after each change (see Working with Source Code in the Org Mode manual).

You can add the code to your init file and restart Emacs to test it out, but if you want to tweak it, I recommend the workflow above. BTW, I also had to stop and do some research (e.g. the table handling was not something I had done before, so it required some research). And the editing part took a while because of the various possibilities (tags, colons in the headline in various places): I came up with something that more or less worked, but decided that it was the better part of valor to stop tinkering and just declare its limitations.

I took the time to fully understand it and try it, I had to fix a typo (texts), it works! Thanks again you made my day :)

Sorry for the typo: I fixed it in my code and forgot to fix it in the answer. Fixed now - thanks!

If you have other such questions, you might also want to post them in French on https://lists.sr.ht/~bzg/emacsfr (and see https://emacs-doctor.com for IRL workshops!)

Thanks for the mailing list link, I didn't knew about it! And for emacs-doctor I added it in my agenda long ago so I see it pop every now and then, but was unable to attend a single time (or maybe just once online) ☹
